# Issues opening files created in 2.8 in 2.83

Tags: installation, system

Today I uninstalled blender completely from my computer after using 2.8 for a long time. i kept all the files and even opened the files on another computer in the same version (2.83) that i installed newlt on my own computer after the uninstall of the older version. I can use 2.83 with no issue what soever but when i try to open or append things from any of my existing files created in 2.8 the mesh looks exploded for lack of better term. the outline is correct but its not all messed up. this is happening with ALL my files. HELP picture is of an appended group of objects from my most recently worked on filees. i was literally working on it in 2.8 this morning before the uninstall and switch and it worked totally fine. Help.

EDIT: I just switched over to cycles and in cycles render my stuff all looks perfect, textures and all. i will attach a screenshot of that as well. its still messed up in the normal editting viewport as well as lookdev.

As you can see in the image from different angles the exploding gets worse and changed randomly while moving around the screen but the outline of the objects are clearly correct.[![enter image description here]

1. [image: List item]
2. [image: List item]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem with blender is that when you try to a file from an older version on a new version, or a file from a new version on an old version, blender sometimes doesn't find data that was present in the version the file was made in when trying to open on a different version. The best thing to do is open this file with 2.8 or tediously fix all the problems manually.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That actually does help a lot. All i could find was people saying that 2.8 to 2.8x shouldnt be an issue only when jumping between 2.79 and earlier. thanks. what about exporting as obj or fbx and importing to new version?

Comment: That works fine, though I will give you a suggestion, go with .fbx format, this is because the mesh retains the same size as the original, unlike .obj, in which the size is increased. One more good factor is that you can easily upload a .fbx file into a game engine compared to a .obj file. What others say is partially true, 2.79 to 2.8 and 2.8x won't work, as you won't be able to open it, but 2.8 to 2.8x does cause a few problems, thought they are normally fixable.

Comment: ALL of my stuff has been created in 2.8. I have a lot of parts to rigged characters that i need to be able to appened and link to other scenes to create animations without making enormous files. im having issues with ALL my files opening in ALL other versions. ive tried 2.82, 2.9, in ALL of them this EXACT thing with the exploded looking objects happens

Comment: so just export as fbx and import in the new version. gonna try that.

Comment: Good luck, it should work if you import it as a .fbx file than any other format because they take up less space than any other format. This is because .fx files are made to be game-ready, so they would technically have a low file size so that you experience fewer crashes in your game. Along with that, .fbx formats were specifically built for objects with rigs, so go .fbx

Comment: what is still making me think i have an issue is the fact that before i did the uninstall and new installation i had backed up everything to google drive and opened the same file on another computer with 2.83 on it to make sure i wouldnt have these problems because ive had them before. And everything was totally fine. I think my problem is something with the directory layout. I had 2.8 installed to the system and other versions zip files in OTHER locations (desktop) i think someting involving this is my problem

Comment: I guess it might have been a problem with a directory or something. To actually be able to understand why this happened, you need to be an expert dev, because this is all API and stuff.

Comment: Yeah, thinking more on that answer, the issues dont make sense for files that are all WITHIN 2.8x. Its doing the same thing for files from blendswap as well and those work for everyone. And I have 2.8 back on here now as well as still troubleshooting 2.83 and 2.8 works totally fine.I just dont know it could be. If ANYONE has had this issue after doing one of the recent updates DO SAY SO. I cant seem to find anyTHING, anyWHERE to help.

Comment: @GabeSobczak Even I know it should work, but it doesn't. I know this from personal experience. To actually be able to understand it, you need to be like a full-on, 10-year experienced back-end developer if you want to fully understand it. At this point, all I can say is it works, but comes with problems.